# postgres autovacuum count is too high

Tags: postgresql

There is a massive table (~400m recs), the number of changes coming to this table is between 10k-200k. The autovacuum threshold and scale factor was too high for autovacuum to kick off. Lowered the threshold using below

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table SET (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 10000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 10000);
```

So there was no autovacuum happening on the table until 7/29 6.45 (below is the snapshot of pg_stat_all_tables taken every 15 minutes. Looks like ~147k updates came in that morning, which should have triggered autovacuum around 14 times based on the threshold. What I fail to understand is why 921 autovacuum's happened that morning. Does this autovacuum counter gets increased on some other conditions too? Due to so many autovacuum's processes using this table got impacted (in terms of performance).[image: pg_stat_all_tables snapshot of every 15 mins]

Comment: That certainly looks strange.  Is there anything in the log file about vacuums?  What is the full version?  What is the OS?

Comment: @jjanes this is from rds aurora for postgres 11.6, unfortunately the logs are done, as rds logs are kept for couple of days in our environment. Does autovacuum count get incremented even if it cannot get the lock required for vacuum? Trying to think of possibilities which could have got the autovacuum count so high.

Comment: Stock PostgreSQL doesn't increment the count if it can't get the lock.  Aurora might be different as it has been heavily modified, but I don't know why they would have changed that part.  With no log files, I don't think there is much more you can do.  Maybe increase your log retention (and set `log_autovacuum_min_duration`) in case it happens again.